# "Good" eigenstates for hydrogen atom in first excited state in an electric field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, hydrogen

Consider a hydrogen atom in the first excited state that is being kept in an external electric field of strength $\lambda E_{ext}\mathbf {\hat{k}}$ . This electric field causes the splitting of the degenerate energy levels. In the theory of first order degenerate perturbation theory, "good" eigenstates are those degenerate eigenstates to which the perturbed wavefunctions of the split energy levels approach when $\lambda \rightarrow 0$ . These "good" eigenstates, in general, are the eigenvectors of the matrix defined by $$\mathbf W_{ij} = \lt\psi_i | H' | \psi_j\gt$$where H' is the perturbation in the hamiltonian and $\psi_i$ are some basis of the degenerate states. Suppose the energy level E is $n-$fold degenerate. I have no issues if the matrix $\mathbf W$ has $n$ eigenvectors. But for the specific example I am talking about (namely the Stark Effect for a first excited hydrogen atom), even though the unperturbed degeneracy of the $1^{st}$ excited state is $4$ (ignoring spin), we get only $2$ eigenvectors for $\mathbf W$, namely: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_{200}\pm\psi_{210})$$ My question is this:

- What is the physical interpretation of this mathematical outcome?
- Does this mean that if we now change the external electric field
  according to $\lambda\rightarrow 0$ then the hydrogen atom can
  **only** return to a state that is a linear combination of the two eigenvectors regardless of its initial first excited state?

Thanks!

Comment: The states $|\psi_{211}\rangle$ and $|\psi_{21-1}\rangle$ are also eigenstates of the full Hamiltonian $H + H'$ in the Stark effect.  They key is to realize that since $H'|\psi_{211}\rangle = H'|\psi_{21-1}\rangle = 0$, these states remain eigenstates of the full Hamiltonian;  it's just that the energy is unchanged relative to the unperturbed system.